# How can I compose a new GSP page out of two existing GSP pages?

Tags: grails

How can I compose a new GSP page out of two existing GSP pages?  example if I want to show both Books and Authors in one GSP page is it possible using tow tab type button click on it and page show on same page?

Comment: I'd suggest reading about `<g:include>` and `<g:render>` in the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest) under "Tags".

Comment: you can use `<g:render template="">` to render page, js for tabs